# Create DNS record set change remains pending

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I'm using the Home Assistance Let's Encrypt Add-in which writes some TXT records in DNS to validate if I'm owner of the domain. Unfortunally the record are not created and the DNS log in Google is showing that they are PENDING.
Any ideas what could causing this. Is they are way to get additional info what is holding this update?

> Request
> Change > deletions
> Change > deletions 1
> Name _acme-challenge.famderidder.com.
> Rrdata "mhJ0sTjvBx2yghsY-yI4vGt6-XoZUqvnx-PTdyz1u4M"
> Ttl 60
> Type TXT
> Project dns-hosting-330318
> Response > change
> Deletions Deletions 1
> Name _acme-challenge.famderidder.com.
> Rrdata "mhJ0sTjvBx2yghsY-yI4vGt6-XoZUqvnx-PTdyz1u4M"
> Ttl 60
> Type TXT
> Id 20
> Start time 2021-10-28T18:01:28.405Z
> **Status PENDING**
>
> User
> famderidder-service-account@dns-hosting-330318.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> Resource name managedZones/5133864168634041253 Request Change >
> additions Change > additions 1 Name
> _acme-challenge.famderidder.com. Rrdata xW0iwr-zSJBAN5cFE1Lripv7mBKRXWIu57JljkNkQ5g Ttl 60 Type TXT Project
> dns-hosting-330318 Response > change Additions Additions 1 Name
> _acme-challenge.famderidder.com. Rrdata "xW0iwr-zSJBAN5cFE1Lripv7mBKRXWIu57JljkNkQ5g" Ttl 60 Type TXT Id 1
> Start time 2021-10-28T09:34:39.726Z **Status PENDING**

Comment: More details are required. Is this log entry from Cloud DNS or from Let's Encrypt? How did you create the DNS Resource Record (GUI, CLI, API)? When you create a resource record via API, you must first start a transaction, create the record and then end the transaction. Since there are insufficient details, I am not sure what you have done or the state of the resource record. The log message indicates a **delete** and not a create or insert.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have added another record which is an additions. It's a sequence of 2 actions which are reported on the Google Cloud Platform Console . I don't have any details on the API because that's one of the Add-Ins in Home Assistant. This is working for other I assume otherwise it would not be released. The Add-in is creating the records (so it has access) and reports on failure: 
IMPORTANT NOTES:
   Type:   dns
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for
   _acme-challenge.famderidder.com - check that a DNS record exists
   for this domain

Comment: Do you have a link for the Home Assistant add-in? This might be an issue with the add-in.  However, your question does not have the details to help you at this point.

Comment: I think the code is at: https://github.com/home-assistant/addons/tree/master/letsencrypt

Comment: @JohnHanley, I tried today to run from the commandline and I'm getting the same error. So I assume it's a config error in Google. But there are not details reported so hard to find for me. The error from running via commandline is: Failed authorization procedure. famderidder.com (dns-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.famderidder.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domai